# On any given day a stock will rise,fall or remain the same

Tags: probability

On any given day a stock will rise,fall or remain the same. Assume the probability of each occurrence is the same. Given two stocks find the probability of each of the following outcomes both stock change,only one stock changes and neither stock changes.

So if the three cases are

$P(R)=\frac{1}{3}$ $P(F)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $P(S)=\frac{1}{3}$

So if both stock change would the probability be $P(Change)=\frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: This is correct, assuming that changes in the stocks are independent, which I guess you are supposed to assume, since there isn't enough information to answer the question otherwise.

Comment: The probability of a given stock changing is $\frac{2}{3}$, since it can either rise or fall. So the probability of both stocks changing is $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$.